# react-native how to add image and onpress into touchable

Tags: android, react-native

I have touchable in react native, inside touchable I have image and on press like this

```
 <TouchableHighlight >
  <Image style={styles.imagestyle}
  source={require('./ic_action_name.png')} />
  onPress={() => this.moveToAddNewCustomer()}>
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

When I tried to run the app, I got this error

> React.Childeren.only expected to receive a single React element child

How to fix this?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.moveToAddNewCustomer()}>
    <Image style={styles.imagestyle} source={require('./ic_action_name.png')} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

or

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.moveToAddNewCustomer()}>
    <Image style={styles.imagestyle} source={require('./ic_action_name.png')} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: This solution is not working in iOS. I am using 0.63. What could be the issue?

Comment: @Mighty I suggest you use react-native-material-ripple or TouchableWithoutFeedback.

Answer (score 4):

By default there is no click or events that attached with any of the Views in react native like react.js. There are mainly two Views specifically designed for handling touch events. They are `TouchableOpacity` and `TouchableHighlight`. You can resolve your issue by wrapping your `Image` component with `TouchableOpacity` or `TouchableHighlight`.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.moveToAddNewCustomer()}>
    <Image style={styles.imagestyle} source={require('./ic_action_name.png')} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight

https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity

Answer (score 3):

if

```
TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.moveToAddNewCustomer()}>
    <Image style={styles.imagestyle} source={require('./ic_action_name.png')} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

didn't work, you should put ur image in a `<view>`

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue by using "TouchableWithoutFeedback"

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
       this.moveToAddNewCustomer()}
    }}
>
    <Image
      style={styles.newImage}
      // resizeMode="contain"
      source={require("~/assets/images/test123.png")}
    />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 2):

if

```
TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.moveToAddNewCustomer()}>
<Image style={styles.imagestyle} source={require('./ic_action_name.png')} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

didn't work or even wrap image with view then i recommend you look up in your

`style={styles.imagestyle}`
try to use `zIndex: 10`
there is a small chance that your image has been overlaid by something but it doesn't lose the image.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).