# How can I add onPress function to an Image element in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making an app with React Native and I need a function to be executed when an image is pressed. However, `Image` elements don't have `onPress` functions. I have tried placing the `Image` in a `TouchableOpacity`, `TouchableHighlight`, and a regular `View` element and giving them on press functions yet nothing works. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Rather than *replacing* the `Image` with a `TouchableOpacity` element, did you try to *nest* the `Image` into the `TouchableOpacity`?

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look at the [Pressable API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-native how to add image and onpress into touchable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760824/react-native-how-to-add-image-and-onpress-into-touchable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your help but I figured it out. Instead of using `TouchableHighlight`, `TouchableOpacity`, or `View` instead nest the image in a `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. That's what worked for me. Thanks everyone.